# Where paramaters of a custom function are coming from inside the loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, loop

I have this piece of code and, although it works, I do not understand how.
First, I created a custom post type into my mu-plugins folder:

```
function actor_init() {

$args = array(
    'label' => 'actors',
    'description' => 'hollywood & stuff',
    'supports' => array(
        'thumbnail',
        'title',
        'editor',
        'comments'
        ),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,

);


register_post_type('actor', $args);

}
```

then, in functions.php I hooked it.

```
add_action( 'init', 'actor_init' );
```

Also, inside functions.php I created a function to display, if there is, the title of the post / page / custom-post

```
<?php
function provahel($arg) {

   if (!$arg['title']) {
      $arg['title'] = get_the_title();
   }
?>

   <h1><?php echo $arg['title'] ?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Finally, In my page.php, single-actor.php and single.php files I call the function inside the loop.

```
<?php
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post();

    provahel($argf);
?>
```

On the front end, correctly the title of the post gets rendered, either if it is a page, a post or the custom-post-type (in this case actor). Why? How Wordpress knows what parameter is passed into the provahel() functions? What is this parameter $argf (P.S. could be called in any way and it would still work)?
Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in the documentation for [`get_the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/):

> **$post**
>   (int|WP_Post) (Optional) Post ID or WP_Post object. *Default is global $post*.

If you don't supply a post object or post ID, it defaults to using the global `$post` variable.

When you call `the_post()` within the loop, this populates the global `$post` variable with the data from the current post within that loop.

EDIT:

`get_the_title` gets the current post object:

```
$post = get_post( $post );
```

`get_post` then accesses the global `$post` if nothing was passed to it:

```
$post = $GLOBALS['post'];
```

Comment: Thanks, so $post is passed also into custom functions where the parameters are not specified? (sorry, I meant parameters, not arguments)

Comment: Nothing is passed, it is a global variable, see edit above. Also, see [the PHP documentation for variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), which explains how globals work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `provahel()` sets the value of title within the `if` statement as quoted below:

```
if (!$arg['title']) {
      $arg['title'] = get_the_title(); // Here you sets the $arg['title'] to current page' title
   }
```

So if you don't assign a value to $argf in page.php, your function will render the title of current page.
To display something else, you need to assign a valid value to  `$argf['title']` like this, before calling your function, in page.php

```
 $arg['title'] = "My Custom title...";
```